# Random questions in php quiz with no repeat of questions

Tags: php

This is the php code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['stdname']))
          {
$result=executeQuery("select stdanswer,answered from studentquestion where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";");
$r1=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$result=executeQuery("select * from question where testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." Order by rand() ");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

1. > 
                  2. > 
                  3. > 
                  4. > 
                   
With this code the questions are coming in random manner but the actual problem is questions are getting repeated how to solve this repeated problem from the above code

--

### -- Table structure for table `question`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `question` (
  `testid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qnid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `question` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optiona` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionb` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optionc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optiond` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correctanswer` enum('optiona','optionb','optionc','optiond') DEFAULT NULL,
  `marks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`testid`,`qnid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `question`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `studentquestion`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `studentquestion` (
  `stdid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `testid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `qnid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `answered` enum('answered','unanswered','review') DEFAULT NULL,
  `stdanswer` enum('optiona','optionb','optionc','optiond') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stdid`,`testid`,`qnid`),
  KEY `testid` (`testid`,`qnid`),
  CONSTRAINT `studentquestion_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`stdid`) REFERENCES `student` (`stdid`),
  CONSTRAINT `studentquestion_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`testid`, `qnid`) REFERENCES `question` (`testid`, `qnid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `studentquestion`

LOCK TABLES `studentquestion` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `studentquestion` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `studentquestion` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

Answer (score -1):

```
// select the questions id's already answered by the current student
$result=executeQuery("select qnid, stdanswer,answered from studentquestion where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid'].";");
$already_answered_qns = array();
while($r1=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($already_answered_qns, $r1['qnid']);
}


// select a question excluding the already answered questions
$result=executeQuery("select * from question where testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid not in (".implode(', ', $already_answered_qns).") Order by rand() ");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: using above code also the questions are getting repeated

Comment: Sorry. Edited the first query. Please check again

Comment: as per you above edited first query i made the changes but now the questions and its options are not getting displayed when the test starts

Comment: i have further added the code plz see my edited questions again

Comment: Yes. Can you please provide the table structures also?

Comment: ok @Aswani Prakash i have added the table structure too in the above edited code

Comment: Please provide the studentquestion table structure too

Comment: provided the studentquestion table structure too now plz see it @aswani Prakash